# How to use Dagger 2 BindsOptionalOf

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am building an Android app using Dagger 2 which supports Bluetooth if it's available. I want to inject the BluetoothAdapter dependency with Dagger.

I know about one way of injecting `null` values with Dagger, which is to annotate the Provider method in the Module, the dependency declaration in the Component and the parameter at the injection site with `@Nullable`. But to make it clearer that the BluetoothAdapter is an *optional* dependency (the rest of the app can also work without BT and should also work on the emulator), I wanted to declare the dependency as an `Optional<BluetoothAdapter>` as described [in the official docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#optional-bindings).

I have a Provider method in my module:

```
@Provides
static BluetoothAdapter providesBluetoothAdapter(MainApplication application) {
    ...
}
```

and a corresponding declaration in the component:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter();
```

As per the instructions, I changed the injection sites to `Optional<BluetoothAdapter>`, made my module abstract and added the following abstract method in the module:

```
@BindsOptionalOf abstract BluetoothAdapter optionalBluetoothAdapter();
```

However it still fails with a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method` exception when run on an emulator.
That's when I thought that maybe I misunderstood the purpose of `@BindsOptionalOf` and removed the `BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter();` declaration from my component to see if it depends on whether the dependency is declared in the component. Still doesn't work.

What am I missing? Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do with an optional binding since methods annotated with `@BindsOptionalOf` must be abstract?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not quite using @BindsOptionalOf the way it's meant to be used. @BindsOptionalOf is best for bindings that *may be present or absent at compile time*, and as such is best for *reusable modules*. It won't help you for runtime presence or absence.

Let's say that you are building a reusable library:

```
@Module public abstract class BluetoothAdapterModule {
  @Provides
  static BluetoothAdapter providesBluetoothAdapter(MainApplication application) {
    ...
  }
}

@Module public interface FooModule {
  // This consumes BluetoothAdapter when it happens to be present.
  @BindsOptionalOf BluetoothAdapter bindOptionalBluetoothAdapter();

  // Assume the Foo implementation injects Optional<BluetoothAdapter>.
  @Binds Bar bindBar(Foo foo);
}
```

Here, when FooModule and BluetoothAdapterModule are bound into the same Component, there will be a binding for BluetoothAdapter. In a different Component or application where you haven't included BluetoothAdapterModule, there would be no binding for BluetoothAdapter, and if you were to depend on BluetoothAdapter directly from Foo (including `@Nullable BluetoothAdapter`) your compilation would fail.

However, with @BindsOptionalOf, you can rely on Dagger to inform you whether or not your `BluetoothAdapter` is present: You inject `Optional<BluetoothAdapter>` instead. If the binding is available, the Optional will be "present" and `get` will return a BluetoothAdapter; and if it is not available, the Optional will be "absent". (Of course, as described in the [@BindsOptionalOf docs](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/BindsOptionalOf.html), you can also inject `Optional<Provider<BluetoothAdapter>>` and `Optional<Lazy<BluetoothAdapter>>` and so forth to further control when and where your object is instantiated.)

In those cases, `@BindsOptionalOf` is required only to confirm to Dagger that it should manage the creation of that Optional instance; otherwise, it would throw a compile-time exception on the assumption that you've made a mistake and forgotten to bind an Optional instance you've created.

To reflect the presence or absence of Bluetooth *known only at runtime*, you'll need to use `@Nullable` or a separate injectable `BluetoothAdapterHolder` you write. You could also bind an `Optional<BluetoothAdapter>` explicitly as mentioned above, creating it explicitly with the presence or absence characteristics that match your needs. At that point, you wouldn't use @BindsOptionalOf because you're not relying on Dagger to reflect the presence/absence: You're controlling it yourself.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, although it is hard to comprehend in the current explanation style.